# How to transform a subset columns of an all string data frame in to numeric?

Tags: r, string, dataframe

All of my data comes in character format. When I try transforming a subset of the data in to numeric using `apply` it doesn't seem to work.

```
df2  <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(1:9),3,3))
df2[,-2]  <-  apply(df2[,-2], 2, as.numeric)
apply(df2, 2, class)
```

Could somebody point me out what I am doing wrong in the example above?
Thanks

Comment: A matrix in R can only hold values of the same type. You cannot change some of the values to numeric and leave some others as characters. If you want different data types, you can use a data.frame, but even then, you can only have one data type per column.

Comment: Just `df2 <- data.frame(df2,stringsAsFactors=F)` after your first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above.. a `matrix` in R can only hold values of the same type in all columns. You cannot change some of the values to numeric and leave some others as characters. If you want different data types, you can use a `data.frame`, but even then, you can only have one data type per column.

For your example case:

```
df2  <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.character(1:9),3,3))
```

will create a data.frame with `factor`s in each column. If you want to convert the second column to `numeric`, you can do:

```
df2$V2 <- as.numeric(levels(df2$V2))[df2$V2]
```

Or

```
df$V2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$V2))
```

So you don't need to use `apply` in this case.

```
str(df2)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ V1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# $ V2: num  4 5 6
# $ V3: Factor w/ 3 levels "7","8","9": 1 2 3
```

If you wanted to convert all columns to numeric, you can do:

```
# if the columns were factors before:
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(i) as.numeric(levels(i))[i])
```

Or

```
# if the columns were characters before:
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.numeric)
```